# Duplicate records are being inserted into DB inside a queued job - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, queue

I am using database driver for queues and have dispatched a job

```
SomeRandomJob::dispatch($eloquentCollection);
```

Now inside `SomeRandomJob` I have the loop that is looping over this `$eloquentCollection` and inserting records into db

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class SomeRandomJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    public $eloquentCollection;


    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($eloquentCollection)
    {
        $this->eloquentCollection = $eloquentCollection;
    }
    

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        foreach ($eloquentCollection as $data) {
            SomeTable::insert([
                'name'=>'Random',
                'data_id'=>$data->id,
            ]);    
        }
    }

    

}
```

This job is queued and processed successfully. But issue here is that lets suppose `$eloquentCollection` has `3` records then after the job is processed the `SomeTable` should have the `3` records but instead it has `6` records like following

| name | data_id |
| --- | --- |
| Random | 3 |
| Random | 2 |
| Random | 2 |
| Random | 1 |
| Random | 1 |
| Random | 1 |

Comment: did you debug the job ? haw many time it run ? what is inside the collection "$eloquentCollection" (that is undefined in your example). You are over simplifying the code posted in your quest which will make helping you near impossible.

Comment: I have debugged it through the telescope. The job ran once and ```$eloquentCollection``` has 3 records init.

Comment: then your issue is in the `handle()` method. please post a more complete version.